# Select dropdown (option, select) css javascript

Tags: javascript, css, select, dropdown, html-select

I'm currently trying to make a select dropdown (option, select) with a design like the following picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2ozs.png)

When selected > 10 then the select dropdown option appears input text to fill in the desired amount.

Has anyone ever made something like this.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you got so far and where specifically did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll just add an if statement for > 10 then the input display will change from none to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of drop down list requested **can not** be constructed simply using a combination of HTML select and option elements. This is because the only permitted content type of [Option elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) is text, although HTML character entities may be used. (If you need to expand character references when setting an option element's content, use its `innerHTML` property instead of `texContent`.)

I would suggest searching for an already available HTML/JavaScript/CSS widget fulfilling a similar purpose, whether it be a self contained package or library plugin, before starting to write your own code from scratch.